# Domain isn't loading with www

Tags: web-services, dns

I have a problem with my webserver, i have just added a domain to it, everything is working fine if i type the URL without "www." but as soon as i type www. it comes up with a find a domain search page.

So if i went to the site mysite.com it runs just fine, but if i use www.mysite.com its like the domain doesn't exist....

Does anyone know why this is happening or how to get around it?

Thanks for the help, i really don't know what other information to add to this post so please ask if needed.

Comment: You can add DNS entry for `www` in your webhosting configuration console

Comment: Do you know where i can see an example of that? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: what's your webhost and/or domain provider? most providers have a FAQ for this kind of job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better off asking this on webmasters.stackexchange.com. But either www.mysite.com isn't registered in DNS, or your webserver doesn't know how to respond to requests for it. Use a service like dnsbench.com to check the DNS setup, and if that's OK, you'd need to identify your webserver for further help.

Answer (score 0):

What's your domain name provider? I had the same issue once with godaddy but if you just set your nameservers wait a full 24 hours. It might happen that the site without www's will work before the www.

Comment: Maybe that is the case, i'll have to check back tomorrow. The domain is with fasthost.com as is the hosting.